# How do I delete an image after a collision in pygame?

Tags: python, image, pygame, collision-detection

I'm making a game involving powerups using python. There is a random chance of one spawning and it blits its image on the screen. it picks a random powerup from a list once the player's body (The captain in this scenario) collides with it. I'm checking the collision with a rectangle at the position of the image (Same size) and attempting to delete the rectangle, and the image once a collision happens. How can I do this?  This is my attempt so far, however, I keep receiving the error: "List assignment index out of range" and it highlights the line: del PowerYList[Spot]. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
if random.randint(1,2500) == 2500:
            PowerY = random.randint(125,585)
            PowerRect = Rect(930, PowerY, 50,50)
            PowerYList.append(PowerY)
            PowerRects.append(PowerRect)


        for X in PowerYList:
            Screen.blit(PowerUp, (930, X))

        Radius = 0   
        for X in PowerRects:
            if X.colliderect(Rect(942, CaptainY, 15, 30)) == True:
                Power = random.choice(PowerUps)
                Power = "Nuke"

                Spot = PowerRects.index(X)
                del X
                del PowerYList[Spot]

                if Power == "Health":
                    if Health <= 85:
                        Health += 15
                    else:
                        Health += 100-Health

                elif Power == "Nuke":
                    Radius = 0 
                    for Y in range(1,50):
                        draw.circle(Screen, ORANGE, (500, 350), Radius+50)
                        draw.circle(Screen, RED, (500,350), Radius)
                        Radius += 5

                    Gigabits = []
                    Gigabits_Heads = []
                    Gigabit_Health = []
                    S_Gigabits = []
                    S_Gigabits_Heads = []
                    S_Gigabit_Health = []
```

Comment: I can't seem to see what `Spot` is in your code.

Comment: Providing a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example will help others help you. Yypically, you want to blit your background image (or fill) in the rectangle from the object you just removed. You're also doing a lot of manual work, I'd recommend you use [sprites](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html) and sprite groups

Comment: Read [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). ie. for variables we use `lower_case_names`, for classes we use `CamelCaseNames`.

Comment: always put full error message (Traceback) in question (as text, not screenshot). There are other useful informations.

Comment: why do you search `Spot` in `PowerRects` and delete `Spot` only from `PowerYList` ? If you remove elements from `PowerYList` then it have to be shorter then `PowerRects` and you have to get error with index. You have to delete from both or search `Spot` in `PowerYList`

Comment: maybe you should keed both elements on one list `Powers.append( (PowerY, PowerRect) )` or event better use only `PowerRect` because you can always get `PowerRect.y` instead of `PowerY` - so `PowerY` seems useless.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example I've constructed to demonstrate sprite removal upon collision with the mouse. See answers [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43480642/7675174) for other methods

```
import random
import pygame

screen_width, screen_height = 640, 480
def get_random_position():
    """return a random (x,y) position in the screen"""
    return (random.randint(0, screen_width - 1),  #randint includes both endpoints.
            random.randint(0, screen_height - 1)) 

def get_random_named_color(allow_grey=False):
    """return one of the builtin colors"""
    if allow_grey:
        return random.choice(all_colors)
    else:
        return random.choice(non_grey)

def non_grey(color):
    """Return true if the colour is not grey/gray"""
    return "grey" not in color[0] and "gray" not in color[0]

all_colors = list(pygame.colordict.THECOLORS.items())  
# convert color dictionary to a list for random selection once
non_grey = list(filter(non_grey, all_colors))

class PowerUp(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        width, height = 12, 10
        self.color, color = get_random_named_color()
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(color)
        # Fetch the rectangle object that has the dimensions of the image
        # Update the position by setting the values of rect.x and rect.y
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect().move(*get_random_position())

    def update(self):
        """move to a random position"""
        self.rect.center = get_random_position()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Sprite Collision Demo')
    clock = pygame.time.Clock() #for limiting FPS
    FPS = 60
    exit_demo = False

    #create a sprite group to track the power ups.
    power_ups = pygame.sprite.Group()
    for _ in range(10):
        # create a new power up and add it to the group.
        power_ups.add(PowerUp())

    # main loop
    while not exit_demo:
        for event in pygame.event.get():            
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                exit_demo = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    exit_demo = True
                elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                    power_ups.update()
            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
                for _ in range(10):
                    power_ups.add(PowerUp())
        # check for collision
        for p in power_ups:
            if p.rect.collidepoint(pygame.mouse.get_pos()):
                power_ups.remove(p)
                print(f"Removed {p.color} power up")

        screen.fill(pygame.Color("black")) # use black background
        power_ups.draw(screen)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(FPS)
    pygame.quit()
    quit()
```