# Wall sprite not showing up on screen after certain coordinates in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

Trying to make collision detection as means to make sprites bounce off one another, but my wall sprites aren't showing up after coords (5, 5)
I wasn't sure if maybe it had to do with fill and colorkey both being white, or the fact that pygame.Surface(x, y) is the same as the x, y for the rect.

Here's my wall class:

```
class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self, color, h, d, x, y):
    super().__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface([x, y])
    self.image.fill(WHITE)
    self.image.set_colorkey(WHITE)

    pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [h, d, x, y])

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

and here's my code for my call to create wall 3 an wall 4:

```
wall3 = Wall(BLACK, 0, 400, 700, 2)
wall_list.add(wall3)
all_sprite_list.add(wall3)

wall4 = Wall(BLACK, 700, 0, 2, 400)
wall_list.add(wall4)
all_sprite_list.add(wall4)
```

Comment: You should provide a [Minimum, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This way it is easier for people to be able to help you. I would guess you have a problem with your coordinate system. You could try creating your image of the desired size and then moving it to the specified position, [e.g.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48292064/7675174)

Comment: and where do you blit() wall on screen ?

Comment: your variables are missleading - you use `x,y` for width and height in `Surface([width, height])` and in `rect(..., [start_x,start_y, width, height])`. And you don't use `x,y` to set position in `Rect()` - `get_rect(x=start_x, y=start_y)`

Comment: to create wall you would need only self.image = Surface([width,height])` and sel.image.fill(color)` and `self.rect = self.image.get_rect(x=x, y=y)`. You don't need `set_color()` and `draw.rect()` Besides your `[h,d,x,y]` seems incorrect and you draw outside Surface - second wall has width 2 but you draw in x=700, first wall has height 2 and you draw in y=400. Surface has own size and coordinates (started always in 0,0) and it doesnt use screen coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for me you have two problems

First: you use missleading names - variables `x,y` should be rather `width, height` but this later.

Second: you assume that surface uses the same coordinates as screen but it not true. It starts at `(0,0)` and ends in your `(x,y)` but you try to draw rect in position `(h,d)` which is outside surface.

So in line

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [h, d, x, y])
```

you need `(0,0)` instead of `(h,d)`

```
pygame.draw.rect(self.image, color, [0, 0, x, y])
```

and you have to use `(h,d)` with `Rect()`

```
self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
self.rect.x = h
self.rect.y = d
```

Frankly, `draw.rect()` will use all surface so you could do the same using only `fill()`

```
def __init__(self, color, h, d, x, y):
    super().__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface([x, y])
    self.image.fill(color)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = h
    self.rect.y = d
```

If you use better names for variables then you get

```
def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height):
    super().__init__()

    self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
    self.image.fill(color)

    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = x
    self.rect.y = y
```