# How to Make a Collision with Two Sprites in Pygame? How to Continue Sprite Loops?

Tags: loops, pygame, collision

I'm having a bit trouble trying to make a collision (and a few other problems) with my sprites in pygame. What I'm trying to do is when a small fork (the sprites are named mini1, mini2, etc.) hits the potato, a heart should disappear. I'm not even sure how to start the collision. When I was looking it up, there was mention of using a class, but I had not learned that so I did not use that method.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pygame, sys
from pygame_functions import * 

pygame.mixer.pre_init(44100,16,2,4096)
pygame.init()

width = 1200
height = 750
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((480, 320))
pygame.display.set_caption('Space Potato')
screenSize(width, height)                            
setBackgroundImage("space.bmp")              
pygame.mixer.music.load("bgmusic.wav")

pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.5)
pygame.mixer.music.play(-1)

door = makeSprite("door.png")
moveSprite(door, 570, 30)
showSprite(door)

potato = makeSprite("potato.bmp") 
moveSprite(potato, 550, 650)                    
showSprite(potato)

mini1 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini1)
mini1x = 590
mini1y = 150

mini2 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini2)
mini2x = 590
mini2y = 150

mini3 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini3)
mini3x = 590
mini3y = 150

mini4 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini4)
mini4x = 590
mini4y = 150

mini5 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini5)
mini5x = 590
mini5y = 150

mini6 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini6)
mini6x = 590
mini6y = 150

mini7 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini7)
mini7x = 590
mini7y = 150

mini8 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini8)
mini8x = 590
mini8y = 150

mini9 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini9)
mini9x = 590
mini9y = 150

mini10 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini10)
mini10x = 590
mini10y = 150

mini11 = makeSprite("minifork.bmp")
showSprite(mini11)
mini11x = 590
mini11y = 150

fork = makeSprite("fork.bmp")
moveSprite(fork, 570, 100)
showSprite(fork)

heart1 = makeSprite("heart.bmp")
moveSprite(heart1, 10, 10)
showSprite(heart1)

heart2 = makeSprite("heart.bmp")
moveSprite(heart2, 60, 10)
showSprite(heart2)

heart3 = makeSprite("heart.bmp")
moveSprite(heart3, 110, 10)
showSprite(heart3)


xPos = 550                                     
yPos = 650 
xSpeed = 0 
ySpeed = 0
moveSprite(potato,xPos, yPos)

while True:
    mini1y += 10
    if mini1y == height - 10:
        mini1y = 150
        mini1x = 590
    moveSprite(mini1, mini1x, mini1y)

    mini2x -= 10
    mini2y += 5
    if mini2y == height - 10:
        mini2y = 150
        mini2x = 590
    moveSprite(mini2, mini2x, mini2y)

    mini3x += 2
    mini3y += 10
    if mini3y == height - 10:
        mini3y = 150
        mini3x = 590
    moveSprite(mini3, mini3x, mini3y)

    mini4x += 15
    mini4y += 2
    if mini4y == height - 10:
        mini4y = 150
        mini4x = 590
    moveSprite(mini4, mini4x, mini4y)

    mini5x -= 5
    mini5y += 10
    if mini5y == height - 10:
        mini5y = 150
        mini5x = 590
    moveSprite(mini5, mini5x, mini5y)

    mini6x -= 10
    mini6y += 7
    if mini6y == height - 10:
        mini6y = 150
        mini6x = 590
    moveSprite(mini6, mini6x, mini6y)

    mini7x += 10
    mini7y -= 2
    if mini7y == height - 10:
        mini7y = 150
        mini7x = 590
    moveSprite(mini7, mini7x, mini7y)

    mini8x -= 5
    mini8y += 10
    if mini8y == height - 10:
        mini8y = 150
        mini8x = 590
    moveSprite(mini8, mini8x, mini8y)

    mini9x += 5
    mini9y -= 10
    if mini9y == height - 10:
        mini9y = 150
        mini9x = 590
    moveSprite(mini9, mini9x, mini9y)

    mini10x -= 10
    mini10y -= 7
    if mini10x == width - 10:
        mini10y = 150
        mini10x = 590
    moveSprite(mini10, mini10x, mini10y)

    mini11x -= 10
    mini11y -= 7
    if mini11x == width - 10:
        mini11y = 150
        mini11x = 590
    moveSprite(mini11, mini11x, mini11y)

    if keyPressed("up"):
        transformSprite(potato, 0, 1)
        yPos -= 7
    elif keyPressed("down"):
        transformSprite(potato, 0, 1)
        yPos += 7
    elif keyPressed("right"):
        transformSprite(potato, 0, 1)
        xPos += 7
    elif keyPressed("left"):
        transformSprite(potato, 0, 1)
        xPos -= 7
    moveSprite(potato, xPos, yPos)

    tick(30)


endWait()
```

I also have another problem where some of my small forks will not loop. I'm not too sure why that is happening as well. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please share a [mcve] so that others can run your code and help you with your problem. In your code, there's no definition for the `makeSprite` function. Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474849/pygame-sprite-collision-with-sprite-group) will help you. Using [sprite groups](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) will make handling your collisions and updates much easier.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a complete answer, but the OP's code would be a lot simpler with some basic classes:

```
class MetaSprite:
    def __init__( self, filename, _x, _y ):
        self.sprite = makeSprite( filename )
        self.x = _x;
        self.y = _y;

    def moveBy( self, _x, _y ):
        self.x += _x;
        self.y += _y;

        # check out of bounds
        if ( self.x >= WINDOW_WIDTH - 10 ):
            self.x = WINDOW_WIDTH
        elif ( self.x <= 10 ):
            self.x = WINDOW_WIDTH - 10
        if ( self.y >= WINDOW_HEIGHT - 10 ):
            self.y = 10
        elif ( self.y <= 10 ):
            self.y = WINDOW_HEIGHT - 10

    def draw( self ):
        moveSprite( self.sprite, self.x, self.y )

    def collidedWith(self, other_sprite):
        return self.sprite.rect.colliderect( other_sprite.rect )
```

Which is a bit more work initially, but then in your code:

```
# create the game objects
potato = MetaSprite( "silver_potatoe.bmp", 400, 200 )

fork_count = 10
all_forks = []
for i in range( fork_count ):
    new_fork = MetaSprite( "minifork.bmp", 590, 150 )
    new_fork.draw()
    all_forks.append( new_fork )
...

# move all the forks a little
all_forks[0].moveBy(  1, 2 )
all_forks[1].moveBy( -1, -1 )
all_forks[2].moveBy( -5, 3 )

...

# Did any fork hit the potato?
for i in range( len( all_forks ) ):
    if ( all_forks[i].collidedWith( potato ) ):
        # TODO - handle fork hitting potatoe
```

Being able to iterate through a list of objects calling the same function in-turn saves a lot of typing.  Having things like bounds-checking only once in the code also saves bug-checking, since the check is on in one place.

The other game objects are basically the same too.  They all share the rule on screen-position bounds, all have a sprite, etc.  This single class could just about handle all objects, with a few extra movement rules.