# I am trying to use random to make the enemy move with a trail, does anyone know why the enemy isn't moving?

Tags: python-3.x

i'm quite new to coding so sorry for hard coding and repeating code. here is the code

```
import random 
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time


GREEN=(0,125,0)
BLUE=(0,0,125)
global Yplayer
Yplayer = 225/2

global Xplayer
Xplayer = 300

playerlinesavedata = []
playercurrent = []


global Xplayerchange
Xplayerchange=0

global Yplayerchange
Yplayerchange=0





global enemydirection

enemydirection = random.randint(1,4) 


global Yenemy
Yenemy = 450

global Xenemy
Xenemy = 300

enemylinesavedata = []
enemycurrent = []

global enemy1
enemy1 = False

global Xenemychange
Xenemychange=0

global Yenemychange
Yenemychange=0

on = True
windowX = 900
windowY = 600

pygame.init()
DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((windowX,windowY),0,32)


def enemymovement(enemy1,Xenemychange,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Yenemy,enemy,enemylinesavedata):
    while enemy1 == True:    
        if enemydirection == 1:
           
            Xenemychange-= random.randint(1,10)
            print("1")
            print(Xenemychange)
            Xenemy+=Xenemychange
            Xenemychange=0
            enemy(enemylinesavedata,Yenemy,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Xenemychange)
            enemy1 = False
        if enemydirection == 2:
           
            
            Xenemychange+= random.randint(1,10)
            print("2")
            print(Xenemychange)
            Xenemy+=Xenemychange
            Xenemychange=0
            enemy(enemylinesavedata,Yenemy,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Xenemychange)
            enemy1 = False
        if enemydirection == 3:
            
            Yenemychange-= random.randint(1,10)
            print("3")
            print(Yenemychange)
            Yenemy+=Yenemychange
            enemy(enemylinesavedata,Yenemy,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Xenemychange)
            Yenemychange=0
            enemy1 = False
            
        if enemydirection == 4:
            Yenemychange+= random.randint(1,10)
            print("4")
            print(Yenemychange)
            
            Yenemy+=Yenemychange
            enemy(enemylinesavedata,Yenemy,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Xenemychange)
            Yenemychange=0
            enemy1 = False
def enemy(enemylinesavedata,Yenemy,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Xenemychange):
    for XnY in enemylinesavedata:
        Yenemy+=Yenemychange
        Xenemy+=Xenemychange
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE, [XnY[0],XnY[1],5,5])
        Yenemy+=Yenemychange
        Xenemy+=Xenemychange

def player(playerlinesavedata):
    for XnY in playerlinesavedata:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,GREEN,[XnY[0],XnY[1],5,5])

def main(Xplayer, Yplayer, Xplayerchange, Yplayerchange, Xenemy, Yenemy, Xenemychange, Yenemychange):
   
    WHITE=(255,255,255)
    BLUE=(0,0,255)
    playerlinesavedata = []
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

    
    pygame.display.update()
    while on == True:
        Yplayer+=Yplayerchange
        Xplayer+=Xplayerchange
        Yenemy+=Yenemychange
        Xenemy+=Xenemychange
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_d:
                    Xplayerchange+=1
                    
                if event.key==K_a:
                    Xplayerchange-=1
                if event.key==K_w:
                    Yplayerchange-=1
                if event.key==K_s:
                    Yplayerchange+=1
            if event.type==KEYUP:
                if event.key==K_a or K_d:
                    Yplayerchange=0
                if event.key==K_w or K_s:
                    Xplayerchange=0


       
        playercurrent = []
        playercurrent.append(Xplayer)
        playercurrent.append(Yplayer)
        playerlinesavedata.append(playercurrent)
        
        Yplayer+=Yplayerchange
        Xplayer+=Xplayerchange

        enemymovement(enemy1,Xenemychange,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Yenemy,enemy,enemylinesavedata)
        enemycurrent = []
        enemycurrent.append(Xenemy)
        enemycurrent.append(Yenemy)
        enemylinesavedata.append(enemycurrent)

                
        Yenemy+=Yenemychange
        Xenemy+=Xenemychange
        
        Yplayer+=Yplayerchange
        Xplayer+=Xplayerchange
        
       
        DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
        
        player(playerlinesavedata)
        enemy(enemylinesavedata,Yenemy,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Xenemychange)
        enemymovement(enemy1,Xenemychange,Yenemychange,Xenemy,Yenemy,enemy,enemylinesavedata)
        pygame.display.update()








        
main(Xplayer, Yplayer, Xplayerchange, Yplayerchange, Xenemy, Yenemy, Xenemychange, Yenemychange)
```

any ideas?

it's supposed to make the enemy move randomly as you have full control. i haven't added it yet but i want is so when you crash in the enemy line you die and if the enemy runs into you they die but you can cross your lines and they can cross theirs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using global variables and passing them as parameter. When the parameters are updated, the global variables are not. You are also adjusting the enemy speed several times per loop.

Here is a cleaner version of your code:

```
import random 
import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time

GREEN=(0,125,0)
BLUE=(0,0,125)

Yplayer = 225//2
Xplayer = 350

playerlinesavedata = []
playercurrent = []

Xplayerchange=0
Yplayerchange=0

Yenemy = 450
Xenemy = 300

enemylinesavedata = []
enemycurrent = []

Xenemychange=0
Yenemychange=0

windowX = 900
windowY = 600

pygame.init()
DISPLAY=pygame.display.set_mode((windowX,windowY),0,32)


def enemymovement():
    global Xplayer,Yplayer,Xenemy,Yenemy
    enemy1 = True
    enemydirection = random.randint(1,4)
    
    # enemy moves toward player
    if Xenemy > Xplayer: enemydirection = 1
    elif Xenemy < Xplayer: enemydirection = 2
    elif Yenemy > Yplayer: enemydirection = 3
    elif Yenemy < Yplayer: enemydirection = 4

    while enemy1 == True:    
        if enemydirection == 1:
            Xenemychange= -random.randint(1,2)
            Xenemy+=Xenemychange
            
        if enemydirection == 2:
            Xenemychange= random.randint(1,2)
            Xenemy+=Xenemychange
            
        if enemydirection == 3:            
            Yenemychange= -random.randint(1,2)
            Yenemy+=Yenemychange
            
        if enemydirection == 4:
            Yenemychange= random.randint(1,2)            
            Yenemy+=Yenemychange
            
        enemylinesavedata.append([Xenemy,Yenemy])
        enemy()
        break
            
def enemy():
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY,BLUE, (enemylinesavedata[-1][0]+2,enemylinesavedata[-1][1]+2), 8)
    for XnY in enemylinesavedata:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,BLUE, [XnY[0],XnY[1],5,5])

def player():
    pygame.draw.circle(DISPLAY,GREEN, (playerlinesavedata[-1][0]+2,playerlinesavedata[-1][1]+2), 8)
    for XnY in playerlinesavedata:
        pygame.draw.rect(DISPLAY,GREEN,[XnY[0],XnY[1],5,5])

def collide():
    global enemylinesavedata, playerlinesavedata
    if ((enemylinesavedata[-1][0] - playerlinesavedata[-1][0])**2 + (enemylinesavedata[-1][1] - playerlinesavedata[-1][1])**2)**.5 < 10:
        playerlinesavedata = playerlinesavedata[-1:] # keep head only

def main():

    global Xplayer,Yplayer,Xenemy,Yenemy,Xplayerchange,Yplayerchange
    WHITE=(255,255,255)
    BLUE=(0,0,255)
    DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)

    
    pygame.display.update()
    while True:
        Yplayer+=Yplayerchange
        Xplayer+=Xplayerchange

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type==KEYDOWN:
                if event.key==K_d:
                    Xplayerchange+=1
                    
                if event.key==K_a:
                    Xplayerchange-=1
                if event.key==K_w:
                    Yplayerchange-=1
                if event.key==K_s:
                    Yplayerchange+=1
            if event.type==KEYUP:
                if event.key==K_a or K_d:
                    Yplayerchange=0
                if event.key==K_w or K_s:
                    Xplayerchange=0


       
        playercurrent = []
        playercurrent.append(Xplayer)
        playercurrent.append(Yplayer)
        playerlinesavedata.append(playercurrent)
        
        Yplayer+=Yplayerchange
        Xplayer+=Xplayerchange

        enemymovement()

        Yplayer+=Yplayerchange
        Xplayer+=Xplayerchange
        
        # check collide
        collide()
                   
        DISPLAY.fill(WHITE)
        
        player()
        enemy()
        pygame.display.update()

main()
```

Comment: Thank You, would you know how to add collision detection to this?

Comment: sorry for being picky but how would i check if he crosses my line or vise versa

Comment: You will need to check for collision for every rectangle in the tail. For checking multiple objects, look into sprite groups: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474849/pygame-sprite-collision-with-sprite-group

Comment: how would one go about adding sprite groups to this code?