# How can I know what enemy collides with me in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using the following:

```
hit = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, door_list, False)
```

Is there any way of checking with what element in `door_list` the player collided with?

Comment: [how do I detect collision in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29640685/how-do-i-detect-collision-in-pygame) may be helpful

Comment: `google pygame detect collision site:stackoverflow.com` should give you _plenty_ resources to read through - there are also dozends of tutorials on collision searchable ... why ask here?

Comment: [pygame-sprite-collision-with-sprite-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43474849/pygame-sprite-collision-with-sprite-group) may be helpful read

Answer (score 0):

[`pygame.sprite.spritecollide`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollide) returns a list containing all *Sprites* in a _Group: that intersect with another *Sprite*:

```py
hit_doors = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, door_list, False)
for door in hit_doors:
    # do something
    # [...]
```